# How to make a proxy mechanism in pyramid framework?

Tags: javascript, python, proxy, pyramid

I have the following problem: 
There is server with pyramid application, he is visible and reachable from internet.
There is server with map, that not visible from internet(both servers are in one local network).
Application server request some data from map server, but those request write in javascript, which runs on client``s machine,requests are directed by ip which of course are local (like 192.168.1.28), and from our local network users can see map, but from internet can`t. 
How to make a tool(maybe additional view or something like that) to redirect requests to map, so that pyramid server works like proxy, if client request map.

Like this:
client from internet <--> pyramid<-->map server

Comment: What are you are looking for is a reverse proxy that can proxy requests to your backend maps server.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to build a HTTP proxy using Pyramid application, though it was not entirely clear why you want to do this with Pyramid or is it the best solution here.

Pyramid and most of modern Python web application use WSGI standard for decoding and handling HTTP requests. Below I present a solution which should work with all WSGI servers. This is a slightly modified [wsgi-proxy application](https://bitbucket.org/dahlia/wsgi-proxy/). The full source code and implementation of the example is available [in pyramid_notebook](https://bitbucket.org/miohtama/pyramid_notebook). This implementation allows proxying only to different `localhost` ports but one can update it to allow arbitrary intranet source IPs.

You can write a Pyramid view which catches all requests to a certain path e.g. `/map-to-internal-server`:

```
def proxy_it(request, port):
    """Proxy HTTP request to upstream server."""
    proxy_app = WSGIProxyApplication(port)
    return request.get_response(proxy_app)
```

Then you can have WSGIProxyApplication which does the logic of connecting the upstream server and streaming the response down to the client:

```
# Courtesy of https://bitbucket.org/dahlia/wsgi-proxy/raw/02ab0dfa8e0078add268e91426e1cc1a52664cf5/wsgi_proxy/__init__.py

import http.client
import logging
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlunsplit, urlunparse, unquote_plus


#: (:class:`frozenset`) The set of hop-by-hop headers.  All header names
#: all normalized to lowercase.
HOPPISH_HEADERS = frozenset([
    'keep-alive', 'proxy-authenticate',
    'proxy-authorization', 'te', 'trailers', 'transfer-encoding',
    'proxy-connection'
    # "upgrade", "connection"
])


def is_hop_by_hop(header):
    """Returns :const:`True` if the given ``header`` is hop by hop.

    :param header: the header name
    :type header: :class:`basestring`
    :returns: whether the given ``header`` is hop by hop or not
    :rtype: :class:`bool`

    """
    return header.lower() in HOPPISH_HEADERS


def reconstruct_url(environ, port):
    """Reconstruct the remote url from the given WSGI ``environ`` dictionary.

    :param environ: the WSGI environment
    :type environ: :class:`collections.MutableMapping`
    :returns: the remote url to proxy
    :rtype: :class:`basestring`

    """
    # From WSGI spec, PEP 333
    url = environ.get('PATH_INFO', '')
    if not url.startswith(('http://', 'https://')):
        url = '%s://%s%s' % (
            environ['wsgi.url_scheme'],
            environ['HTTP_HOST'],
            url
        )
    # Fix ;arg=value in url
    if '%3B' in url:
        url, arg = url.split('%3B', 1)
        url = ';'.join([url, arg.replace('%3D', '=')])
    # Stick query string back in
    try:
        query_string = environ['QUERY_STRING']
    except KeyError:
        pass
    else:
        url += '?' + query_string


    parsed = urlparse(url)
    replaced = parsed._replace(netloc="localhost:{}".format(port))
    url = urlunparse(replaced)
    environ['reconstructed_url'] = url
    return url


class WSGIProxyApplication:
    """WSGI application to handle requests that need to be proxied.
    You have to instantiate the class before using it as WSGI app::

        from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

        app = WSGIProxyApplication()
        make_server('', 8080, app).serve_forever()

    """

    #: (:class:`types.ClassType`) The connection class of :mod:`httplib` module.
    #: It should be a subtype of :class:`httplib.HTTPConnection`.
    #: Default is :class:`httplib.HTTPConnection`.
    connection_class = http.client.HTTPConnection

    def __init__(self, port):
        # Target port where we proxy IPython Notebook
        self.port = port

    def handler(self, environ, start_response):
        """Proxy for requests to the actual http server"""
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__ + '.WSGIProxyApplication.handler')
        url = urlparse(reconstruct_url(environ, self.port))

        # Create connection object
        try:
            connection = self.connection_class(url.netloc)
            # Build path
            path = url.geturl().replace('%s://%s' % (url.scheme, url.netloc),
                                        '')
        except Exception:
            start_response('501 Gateway Error', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
            logger.exception('Could not Connect')
            yield '<H1>Could not connect</H1>'
            return

        # Read in request body if it exists
        body = length = None
        try:
            length = int(environ['CONTENT_LENGTH'])
        except (KeyError, ValueError):

            # This is a situation where client HTTP POST is missing content-length.
            # This is also situation where (WebOb?) may screw up encoding and isert extranous = in the body.
            # https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/8416
            if environ["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST":
                if environ.get("CONTENT_TYPE") == 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8':
                    body = environ['wsgi.input'].read()
                    try:
                        body = unquote_plus(body.decode("utf-8"))

                        # Fix extra = at end of JSON payload
                        if body.startswith("{") and body.endswith("}="):
                            body = body[0:len(body)-1]

                    except Exception as e:
                        logger.exception(e)
                        logger.error("Could not decode body: %s", body)

                    length = len(body)
        else:
            body = environ['wsgi.input'].read(length)

        # Build headers
        logger.debug('environ = %r', environ)
        headers = dict(
            (key, value)
            for key, value in (
                # This is a hacky way of getting the header names right
                (key[5:].lower().replace('_', '-'), value)
                for key, value in environ.items()
                # Keys that start with HTTP_ are all headers
                if key.startswith('HTTP_')
            )
            if not is_hop_by_hop(key)
        )

        # Handler headers that aren't HTTP_ in environ
        try:
            headers['content-type'] = environ['CONTENT_TYPE']
        except KeyError:
            pass

        # Add our host if one isn't defined
        if 'host' not in headers:
            headers['host'] = environ['SERVER_NAME']

        # Make the remote request
        try:

            logger.debug('%s %s %r',
                         environ['REQUEST_METHOD'], path, headers)
            connection.request(environ['REQUEST_METHOD'], path,
                               body=body, headers=headers)
        except Exception as e:
            # We need extra exception handling in the case the server fails
            # in mid connection, it's an edge case but I've seen it
            logger.exception(e)
            start_response('501 Gateway Error', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
            yield '<H1>Could not proxy IPython Notebook running localhost:{}</H1>'.format(self.port).encode("utf-8")
            return

        response = connection.getresponse()

        hopped_headers = response.getheaders()
        headers = [(key, value)
                   for key, value in hopped_headers
                   if not is_hop_by_hop(key)]

        start_response('{0.status} {0.reason}'.format(response), headers)
        while True:
            chunk = response.read(4096)
            if chunk:
                yield chunk
            else:
                break

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        return self.handler(environ, start_response)
```